# Deleting rows from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I have a problem deleting rows from table with parameters. Here is the code:

```
if ($dbProductImageIdNumber) {
$ImagesToDeleteNumber = $dbProductImageIdNumber -1 - $numItemImages;
echo "$dbProductImageIdNumber" . ' ';
echo "$numItemImages" . ' ';
echo "$ImagesToDeleteNumber" . ' ';
echo 'Deleting';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' ,ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'");
}
```

Problem is that `!=` seems to be understood wrongly, maybe I'm dooing syntax mistakes?

Will apreciate any help.

-----EDIT-----

Ok, here what I have now:

```
if ($dbProductImageIdNumber) {
$ImagesToDeleteNumber = $dbProductImageIdNumber -1 - $numItemImages;
echo "$dbProductImageIdNumber" . ' ';
echo "$numItemImages" . ' ';
echo "$ImagesToDeleteNumber" . ' ';
echo "$dbProductId" . ' ';
echo "$dbProductThumbnail" . ' ';
mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' AND ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'");
}
```

Example: my $dbProductId is '16' and $dbProductThumbnail '17'. Qestion is, why this command do not delete any row where post_parent is '16' and ID isn't 17? Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not != but the problem was that you have used "," instead of AND in your code between  post_parent = '$dbProductId' ,ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'"

mysql_query("DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' ,ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'");
}

So, corrent syntax is below.

DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' AND ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'

Comment: Updated my post, please look there. AND was a mistake, but it didn't help.

Comment: DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' AND ID <> '$dbProductThumbnail'

Comment: With `<>` it deletes everything even a row where `ID` is `$dbProductThumbnail`.

Comment: Oh, that was my mistake.. `$dbProductThumbnail` was empty. So now it works! :) Thank you very much! It seems all these answers were rigth then, but I suppose I will mark yours as you helped me the most, and as I can see you need rep points the most too. :)

Answer (score 3):

it should be `AND` and not comma.

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' AND ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` or `OR` in your `WHERE` statement

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts
WHERE post_parent = '$dbProductId' AND ID != '$dbProductThumbnail'
```

Comment: Updated my post, please look there. `AND` was a mistake, but it didn't help.